# MySQL Query returning duplicated results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Fairly new to mySQL . Trying to get a query to work, but keep getting the right results, but duplicated.

Here's the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    band.band_name, concert.venue_name 
FROM 
    band, concert 
WHERE 
    concert.date="2012-10-17" AND band_name 
IN 
    (SELECT band.band_name FROM band WHERE band.band_id 
IN 
    (SELECT tour.band_id from tour where tour.tour_name 
IN 
    (SELECT tour_name from concert where concert.date="2012-10-17")));
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE band (
    band_id      INT,
    band_name    VARCHAR(50),
    genre        VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (band_id) );

CREATE TABLE musician (
    person_id   INT,
    name        VARCHAR(50),
    band_id     INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (band_id) REFERENCES band(band_id) );

CREATE TABLE tour(
    tour_name   VARCHAR(50),
    band_id     INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (tour_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (band_id) REFERENCES band(band_id) );

CREATE TABLE venue(
    venue_name  VARCHAR(30),
    hire_cost   INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (venue_name) );

CREATE TABLE concert(
    concert_id       INT,
    date             DATE,
    tour_name        VARCHAR(50),
    venue_name       VARCHAR(30),
    ticket_sales     INT, 
    PRIMARY KEY      (concert_id),
    FOREIGN KEY      (tour_name) REFERENCES tour(tour_name),
    FOREIGN KEY      (venue_name) REFERENCES venue(venue_name) );
```

I'm totally lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes. See about JOINs. Any beginners book or tutorial would do.

Comment: I'm surprised that a distinct clause fails to remove duplicates. Can you add sample data to your question as text?

Answer (score 1):

Joining tables is the way to go, you do not pile all your conditions into the `where` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    b.band_name, c.venue_name 
FROM concert c 
  join venue v on v.venue_name = c.venue_name -- thats how those 2 tables connect
  join tour t on t.tour_name = c.tour_name    -- thats how those 2 tables connect
  join band b on b.band_id = t.band_id        -- thats how those 2 tables connect
WHERE c.date="2012-10-17"             -- and this gives you all the bandnames and  
                            -- venuenames that play on every concert on this date
```

This way the DB can optimize your query and due to the joins on the tables does not need to scan so much data.